# Missing Variables in Contact Form Using Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a contact form on a landing page that I want to send through with AJAX & PHP but for some reason, the variables are not passing. I am getting the email but the variables are blank. You can go to removed to see the text site, it's not set up with the database on this site though, so if you try to click through nothing will happen.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing my form to not cooperate?

**The HTML**

```
  <form role="form" id="form" name="form" action="submit.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your full name.</span>
    </div>          
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
     <input type="tel" class="form-control input-lg optional" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone (Optional)"/>
      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid phone number.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid email address.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <textarea rows="5" cols="30" class="form-control input-lg" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" ></textarea>
      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a message.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-sm optional" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" checked="checked"> 
      Opt-in to our newsletters to stay up-to-date with the latest information. </label>
      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Would you like to sign up for our newsletter?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <button type="submit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" data-loading-text="Sending..." style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**The Script**

```
//*Form*//  
    $('document').ready(function(){
            $('#form').validate({
                    rules:{
                        "name":{
                            required:true,
                            maxlength:40
                        },
                        "phone":{
                            required:false
                        },
                        "email":{
                            required:true,
                            email:true,
                            maxlength:100
                        },
                        "message":{
                            required:false
                        },
                        "newsletter":{
                            required:false
                        }},

                    messages:{
                        "name":{
                            required:"This field is required"
                        },
                        "phone":{
                            required:"This field is required"
                        },
                        "email":{
                            required:"This field is required",
                            email:"Please enter a valid email address"
                        },
                        "message":{
                            required:"This field is required"
                        },
                        "newsletter":{
                            required:"This field is required"
                        }},

                 submitHandler: function(form){
                    $.ajax ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "submit.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data:{"name":$("#name").text(),"phone":$("#phone").text(),"email":$("#email").text(),"message":$("message").text(),"newsletter":$("#newsletter").checked},
                        target: '#preview',
                        success: function(Result) {
                            alert(Result[0]);
                        $('#formbox').slideUp('fast');
                        $('#success').html();
                        $('#success').show();
                    },
                        failure: function (arg1, arg2) {
                            alert(arg1 + '\n\n' + arg2);
                    },
                        error: function (Result, Error, arg3, arg4) {
                            alert(Result + '\n\n' + Error + '\n\n' + arg3 + '\n\n' + arg4);
                    } 
                });
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

**The PHP**

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

/*
 $checkemail = $_POST['email'];
         if (filter_var($checkemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { echo ""; }
         else { die ("Invalid email, form processing has not completed.");
        }
*/

// check email validity. clean name, phone, and message.

$name = htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$phone = htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$newsletter = htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'newsletter', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)); 

// commit to database
require_once 'db.php';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO contact (name, phone, email, message, newsletter) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $message);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $newsletter, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$pdo->commit();

//form email
    $today = date("Y-m-j");
    $body = "";
    $body .= "Name: $name\n";
    $body .= "Email: $email\n";
    $body .= "Phone: $phone\n";
    $body .= "Message: $message\n";
    $body .= "Newsletter: $newsletter\n";
//send email 'change me to clients address'
    mail("angela@etvsoftware.com","Dogwood Hills Gun Club Contact Form",$body,"angela@etvsoftware.com");

$stmt = null;
$pdo = null;

#What we say when everything goes right
    $result = array(
            "message" => "Your message has been sent. We will respond to you as soon as possible."
    );

    print json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: `.text` should be **.val** see:http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @Dagon That works for the Name, phone and email but not for the message or checkbox.

Comment: `.val` works for textarea to your missing the **#** in that one

Comment: @Dagon When I put that into the message string it still comes up missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
data:{"name":$("#name").text(),"phone":$("#phone").text(),"email":$("#email").text(),"message":$("message").text(),"newsletter":$("#newsletter").checked}
```

You should consider something cleaner and more flexible using [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) like that:

`data: $('#form').serialize()`

This will send all the form fields in the POST request with your ajax call. If this is not working, Please try to `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure what you are getting.

Comment: so can you get all the fields now using that?